# Compartilhar arquivo de html android

Tags: android

Quero compartilhar um `HTML` em forma de arquivo,  e não apenas texto.

Primeiro eu precisaria gerar um arquivo para depois enviar?

```
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(meuHtml));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sim!**

Para compartilhar um arquivo, é preciso criar antes e enviar!

Tente da seguinte forma:

No arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml** adicione a permissão de escrita, para que possamos criar o arquivo antes de enviar!

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Na sua Activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final String HTML = "<html> <body> <h1>Meu HTML compartilhado</h1> </body> </html>";
    private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 9876;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cmd);
    }

    /**
     * Vamos Criar um arquivo chamado shared.html para que possamos compartilhar este!
     */
    public File writeToFile(String data) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(root, "shared.html");
            stream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
            stream.write(data.getBytes());
            return file;
        } finally {
            if (null != stream) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Vertifica se há permissão de escrita, caso não tenha, solicita!
     * Este método é invocado para compartilhar o arquivo!
     */
    private void checkPermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            shared();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Retorno da solicitação da permissão,
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            shared();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "É necessário a permissão de escrita para compartilhar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compartilha o arquivo Html criado
     */
    private void shared() {
        try {
            final File arquivo = writeToFile(HTML);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/html");

            final String filePath = String.format("file://%s", arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
            final String sharingText = String.format("Compartilhando %s...", arquivo.getName());

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sharingText);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharingText);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Cara